# Runaway argument

Tags: errors, align

The following code:

```
\begin{align*} \lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\psi(u)}{\overline{F_I}(u)}&=\left(\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(1+\rho)^{-n}\\
&=\left(\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{n}(1+\rho)^{-n}\\
&=\left(\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\right)\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}(1+\rho)^{-n}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(1+\rho)^{-m}=\frac{(1+\rho)^{-1}}{1-(1+\rho)^{-1}}=\rho^{-1}.\qed \end{align*}
```

produces following error:

```
"! Paragraph ended before \align* was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par "
```

What seems to be the problem?

Edit:

---

Actually, the culprit was the following alignment above the original alignment

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, ngerman, openright, 12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document} 
\begin{align*} 
\frac{\psi(u)}{\overline{F_I}(u)}&=\left(\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\‌​infty}(\frac{\lambda\mu}{c})^{n}\frac{\overline{F_I^{n }}(u)}{\overline{F_I}(u)}\\
&\leq K\left(\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1+\rho\right)^{-n}(1+\epsilon)^{n}<\infty.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The correct command for setting the QED symbol in a final alignment environment is `\qedhere` (assuming you're using `amsthm`).

Comment: Your code compiles fine with the appropriate packages (`amsmath` and `amsthm`), there must be something in your preamble that is causing the problem.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  In this case I suspect that you'll solve your own problem by the time you compose a MWE.

Comment: The error suggests that you are leaving some blank line(s) inside an `align*` environment; if that's so, simply remove those blank lines; otherwise, as Peter Grill suggested, add a MWE.

Comment: There was an alignment over the original alignment, which seems to create the problem:                                                         \documentclass[a4paper, twoside, ngerman, openright, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                                                          \begin{document}

Comment: \begin{align*}
\frac{\psi(u)}{\overline{F_I}(u)}&=\left(\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{\lambda\mu}{c})^{n}\frac{\overline{F_I^{n *}}(u)}{\overline{F_I}(u)}\&\leq K\left(\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1+\rho\right)^{-n}(1+\epsilon)^{n}<\infty.
\end{align*}
\end{document}

Comment: @Chris: please add the code as an edit to your question; comments are not the best place to write a MWE. In the meantime, I've provided an answer.

Comment: Ok Gonzalo, will do from now on!

Comment: Same issue as [brackets - What is "! paragraph ended before \align was complete"? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124764/what-is-paragraph-ended-before-align-was-complete).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an incomplete `\frac` command at the end of the second line of the `align*`, here:

```
\left(\frac{1+\rho\right)
```

perhaps you meant

```
\left(\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\right)
```

Also you end `align*` with `align` (no star), but perhaps that was only a typo in the MWE? Your equation in a complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, ngerman, openright, 12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
\frac{\psi(u)}{\overline{F_I}(u)} &= \left(\frac{\rho}{1 + \rho}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{\lambda\mu}{c})^{n}\frac{\overline{F_I^{n }}(u)}{\overline{F_I}(u)} \\ 
&\leq K\left(\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\right)^{-n}(1+\epsilon)^{n}<\infty.
 \end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, the \frac is the problem, it should not have been there at all: