# What is "! paragraph ended before \align was complete"?

Tags: align, brackets

The following is the piece of code that was working right before I made a few small minor changes.

```
\begin{align}
\langle \prod_{i=1}^{n} \delta_i ^{n_i} y^{m_i}_i  \rangle 
= \sum _ {a_{i=1...n} = 0}^{n_{i=1...n}}   
  \sum_{b_{i=1...n} = 0} ^{m_{i=1...n}}     
  \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left [ ^{n_i}C_{a_i} ( \sum _ {\rho_{\{a_{1\leq i \leq n}\}}}   
  \prod _{B \in \rho_{\{ a_{1 \leq i \leq n} \}} 
  \langle \delta_i ^{\vert B \vert} \rangle _c ) ^{m_i}C_{b_i} 
  ( \sum _ {\rho_{\{b_{1\leq i\leq n}\}}} 
  \prod _{B \in \rho_{\{b_{1\leq i \leq n} \}}} 
  \langle y_i ^{\vert B \vert} \rangle_c ) \right ] \langle 
  \prod_{i=1}^{n} \delta_i ^{n_i - a_i} y_i ^{m_i - b_i} \rangle _{nzl}
\end{align}
```

- Also can I get the innermost pair of `$( )$` brackets to be large using `\left` and `\right`?

Comment: The subscript of the second `\prod` is never closed (i.e. missing `}`). And yes, you can use `\left(` and `\right)` as long it is on one line, not separated by `\\`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel by my count, it's actually the third `\prod`. :-)

Comment: @Adam You are right. I missed the very first `\prod` counting.

Comment: Remark: the same error message can also be caused by having blank line inside the `align` environment. See [Paragraph ended before \align was complete - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203020/paragraph-ended-before-align-was-complete).

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing curly brace to delimit the subscript of the third `\prod` expression.

In the code below, I've also (i) inserted a line break, (ii) increased the sizes of some of the fences, and (iii) replaced `...` with `,\dots,`. Note that the size of the fences is deliberately set so as not to span the subscripts and superscripts of the sum and product symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % use whatever page margins are right for you
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\biggl\langle \prod_{i=1}^{n} \delta_i ^{n_i} y^{m_i}_i \biggr\rangle 
 &= 
\sum _ {a_{i=1,\dots, n} = 0}^{n_{i=1,\dots, n}} 
\sum_{b_{i=1,\dots, n} = 0} ^{m_{i=1,\dots, n}} 
\prod_{i=1}^{n} \Bigg[
  {}^{n_i}C_{a_i} \biggl(
    \sum _ {\rho_{\{a_{1\leq i \leq n}\}}} 
    \prod _{B \in \rho_{\{ a_{1 \leq i \leq n} \}}} 
    \bigl\langle \delta_i ^{\vert B \vert} \bigr\rangle _c 
  \biggr) ^{m_i}\notag\\ 
 &\quad \times C_{b_i}
  \biggr( \sum _ {\rho_{\{b_{1\leq i\leq n}\}}} 
    \prod _{B \in \rho_{\{b_{1\leq i \leq n} \}}} 
    \langle y_i ^{\lvert B \rvert} \rangle_c 
  \biggr) \Bigg] 
  \biggl\langle 
    \prod_{i=1}^{n} \delta_i ^{n_i - a_i} y_i ^{m_i - b_i} 
  \biggr\rangle _{\text{nzl}}
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this huge effort! I have never seen these commands of \bigr, \bigl, \Bigg, \biggr, \biggl. You are saying that these are somehow better than the \left and \right that I use? How do you actually decide what to use?

Comment: @user6818 - You're welcome. There are (at least) two reasons for not using `\left` and `\right` to size the fences, and for using explicit size instructions (\big, \Big, \bigg, and \Bigg) instead: (i) The fences straddle a line break, as is the case with the square brackets in your example. (ii) The fences would be *too big* if sized automatically, as would be the case for the round parentheses and angle brackets in your example. For fences that surround display-style sum and product symbols, Knuth recommends the `\bigg[lr]` sizing instruction.