# Paragraph ended before \align was complete

Tags: align

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\rhead{Homework for Stats Chapter 4\textbackslash Lab}

\cfoot{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
\section{4.4 Excercises}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item For each experiment, list the sample space and the probabilities
          for each outcome. Compute the expected number of heads in each case.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Two independent tosses of a fair coin\\
        \{(HH),(HT),(TH),(TT)\}\\
        $\mathbb{P}(HH)=\frac{1}{4} \mathbb{P}(HT)
                =\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(TH)=\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(TT)
                =\frac{1}{4}$\\

        \begin{align}
        \mathbb{E}\left ( H\right )=\sum _{i=0}H_i\cdot p_i & =2\cdot\frac{1}{4}+1\cdot\frac{1}{4}+1\cdot\frac{1}{4}+0\cdot\frac{1}{4}\\
        & =\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\\
        & =1\\

        \end{align}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Can't see where I'm messing up. I've closed everything. Getting "Paragraph ended before \align was complete.

Comment: Works between $ and $ signs. But not in align

Comment: Please supply a minimum working example. It also helps if you explain what you tried so far.

Comment: Don't leave a blank line just before `\end{align}`

Comment: This works: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}\left ( H\right )=\sum _{i=0}H_i*p_i & =2\cdot\frac{1}{4}+1\cdot\frac{1}{4}+1\cdot\frac{1}{4}+0\cdot\frac{1}{4}\\
    & =\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\\
    & =1
    \end{align}
\end{document}`.

Comment: That was right Harish. What did you change?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). You can highlight code using the `{}` markers at the top of the editing window -- and by using backquotes for inline text.

Comment: Besides not leaving a blank line in `align`, you should also _not_ have a `\\ ` on the last line in an `align`.

Comment: **Remark**: the same error message may also be caused by having extra unbalanced `{` inside the `align` environment. See [brackets - What is "! paragraph ended before \align was complete"? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124764). ■ **See also**: [math mode - Blank lines in align environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10355) ;; [math mode - Why align and equation environment do not tolerate empty lines? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/328779)

Answer (score 12):

You have a blank line in your align environment. I made some modifications to your code: replaced inline `\frac` (too small, in my opinion) with `\mfrac` (=medium-sized fractions, ~80 % of display style fractions) from the `nccmath` package, deleted another blank line and as I think each line of your alignment needs not  be numbered, I took the liberty to replace it with an `aligned` environment, nested in `equation`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Homework for Stats Chapter 4\textbackslash Lab}

\cfoot{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}

\section{4.4 Exercises}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item For each experiment, list the sample space and the probabilities
          for each outcome. Compute the expected number of heads in each case.
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item Two independent tosses of a fair coin\\
        \{(HH),(HT),(TH),(TT)\}\\
        $\mathbb{P}(HH)=\mfrac{1}{4} \mathbb{P}(HT)
                =\mfrac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(TH)=\mfrac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(TT)
                =\mfrac{1}{4}$

        \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}
        \mathbb{E}\left ( H\right )=∑ _{i=0}^4H_i · p_i & =2 · \frac{1}{4}+1 · \frac{1}{4}+1 · \frac{1}{4}+0 · \frac{1}{4}\\
        & =\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\\
        & =1
        \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, God ! What is wrong with empty lines in `aligned` ? :(

Comment: You shouldn't insert empty lines in  multiline environments. It is made to start a new paragraph.

Comment: The whole point of the double slash syntax is to indicate where the lines break. Why must I also not manually add empty lines? This error message is maddeningly unhelpful.

Comment: @JosephGarvin:  That's precisely because it starts a new paragraph (in the TeX sense), so you leave math mode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should have a line break at the end of the last line in an environment. Try removing the last `\\`.

Comment: Nope. Pulled that out with no change