# Paragraph ended before \align was complete for following code

Tags: errors

```
\begin{align}\label{flicker4}
\[{\rm{rank}}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
E&0&{{B_d}}\\
C&{{D_d}}&0\\
0&0&{{D_d}}
\end{array}} \right] = n + {\rm{rank}}{D_d} + {\rm{rank}}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{B_d}}\\
{{D_d}}
\end{array}} \right],\]

\end{align}
```

Comment: Welcomew to TeX. SE¨. Please extend your code snippet to complete small document with `\documentclass{...}` on the beginning and `\end{document}` of its end.

Comment: you can not nested `equation` environment  (`\[ ... \]` ) inside `align` environment!

Comment: Crosslink: Half of the error is caused by [Paragraph ended before \align was complete - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203020/paragraph-ended-before-align-was-complete).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with your code. First of all:

- Empty lines are not allowed inside a display math environment
- `align` is already a math environment, so you shouldn't use `\[ .. \]` inside it.

The code below has some additional suggestions, including using `bmatrix` instead of `array`, using `equation` instead of `align` because there is only one line and no alignment needed, removing a lot of unnecessary braces, and defining a new operator instead of using `\rm` (which has been deprecated for twenty-odd years).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{flicker4}
\rank
\begin{bmatrix}
E & 0   & B_d \\
C & D_d & 0   \\
0 & 0   & D_d
\end{bmatrix} = n + \rank D_d +
\rank \begin{bmatrix}
B_d\\
D_d
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, so I'm not actually entirely sure if `\rank` should be defined as an operator. If someone knows better, please let me know or just edit my code.

Comment: I‘d say it’s quite OK to make it a `\nolimits` operator, exactly as you did (_i.e._, just be careful not to say `\DeclareMathOperator*{\rank}{rank}`!).

Comment: Defining the command as `\rk` would be shorter to type, and I don't think  it's already defined.

Comment: @Bernard Shorter to type, perhaps harder to remember.