# Paragraph ended before split was complete?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, errors, split

I have the following

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i} z_i^2 + \sum_{i}s_it_i &=   \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}z_i^2 + \sum_{P_2}s_it_i+\sum_{R \setminus P_2}s_it_i\\
                             &=     \frac{1}{2}\sum_i z_i^2 + \sum_{P_2}2(n-3-z_i) + \sum_{R \setminus P_2} (n-2-z_i)\\
                             &\ge    \frac{1}{2}\sum_i z_i^2 - \sum_{R} z_i - \sum_{P_2}z_i+ 2(n-3)\sigma + (n-p-q-2)(n-2)\\

    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Compiling gives me the error "Paragraph ended before split was complete", it mentions something about \par afterward. I can't spot any error.

Comment: You have a blank line inside the split environment. Delete it.

Comment: Thank you,  that makes sense.

Comment: Don't forget that no display math environment should contain a blank line (which is used to mark the end of a paragraph in text mode).

Comment: If you want to have an almost blank line there for readability, you can put a single `%` in that line.

Comment: Crosslink: Same issue as [Paragraph ended before \align was complete - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203020/paragraph-ended-before-align-was-complete).