# Paragraph ended before \align was complete

Tags: align

I have a problem that has already been reported here, but I checked and I don't see any `\begin{align}` not closed through `\end{align}`.
Another thing that's bothering me is the `E` for the expected value, it looks different than the ones I saw on article or the one on Wikipedia.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside] {book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document}

\chapter[Nom court chapitre]{My chapter}

$P=\sum_{i=1}^{r} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}X_{i}$
$F_{1}(1) =\sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}(S_{i}(1)-K_{i})$
\begin{align}
P-F_{1}(1) &=\sum_{i=1}^{r} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}X_{i} -\sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}(S_{i}(1)-K_{i}) \\
        &= \sum_{i=1}^{r} (\sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}X_{i}-M_{i}(S_{i}(1)-K_{i}))
\end{align}
donc
\begin{align}
Var(P-F_{1}(1)) &=Var(P) + Var(\sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}(S_{i}(1)-K_{i})) -2Cov(P,F_{1}(1)) \\
            &=Var(P) + \sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}^2Var(S_{i}(1)) -2Cov(\sum_{i=1}^{r} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i} \geqslant 1}X_{i},\sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}(S_{i}(1))) \\
            &=Var(P) + \sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}^2Var(S_{i}(1)) - 2(\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{r} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i} \geqslant 1}X_{i}\sum_{l=1}^{r} M_{l}(S_{l}(1))]-\mathbb{E}[P]\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}(S_{i}(1))]) \\
            &=Var(P) + \sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}^2Var(S_{i}(1)) - 2(\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}}\sum_{l=1}^{r} X_{i}M_{l} \mathbb{E}[\mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i} \geqslant 1}S_{l}(1)]-\mathbb{E}[P]\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}(S_{i}(1))]
\end{align}

Comme la fonction de survie est stochastique, les termes d'espérance et variance de P doivent être détaillés:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}S_{l}(1)]&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}S_{l}(1)/]\kappa_{1}^((1)),\kappa_{1}^((2))] \\
&=\mathbb{E}[S_{l}(l)\mathbb{E}[\mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}/\kappa_{1}^((1)),\kappa_{1}^((2))]
\end{align}
Nous avons également que

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[P] &=\sum_{i=1}^{r} X_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \mathbb{E}[\mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}] \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{r} X_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}/S_{i}(1)]] \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{r} X_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}[T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1/S_{i}(1)]] \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{r} X_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \mathbb{E}[S_{i}(1)]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{r} X_{i}N_{i}\mathbb{E}[S_{i}(1)]
\end{align}
Or nous savons que \\
\begin{center}
$Var(P)= \mathbb{E}[Var(P/S(1))] + Var(\mathbb{E}[P/S(1)])$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I not see \end{document} on your code.

Comment: I do agree with you, but I have it in my document, it's not the source of the problem

Comment: There is a `}` missing in the last line of the third `align` environment: `&=\mathbb{E}[S_{l}(l)\mathbb{E}[\mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}/\kappa_{1}^((1)),\kappa_{1}^((2))]`

Comment: Thank you, very sharp eye. actually it was missing at the end of  \{T_{j}^{i}}
Can you tell me if the expected value looks like mine?

Comment: @NaoufalEB `\kappa_{1}^((2))` should probably be `\kappa_{1}^{(2)}`

Comment: Remark: readers coming here may be able to find their answer in [brackets - What is "! paragraph ended before \align was complete"? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124764/what-is-paragraph-ended-before-align-was-complete).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}/\kappa_{1}^((1))
```

You are missing a brace `}` but also `^(` is not a tex error but only raises the `(` so you probably want

```
\mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}}/\kappa_{1}^{(1)}
```

In addition, never end a paragraph with `\\` so

```
Or nous savons que \\
```

should be

```
 Or nous savons que
```

and never leave a blank line in the source before any display math environment such as `align`

```
\begin{center}
$Var(P)= \mathbb{E}[Var(P/S(1))] + Var(\mathbb{E}[P/S(1)])$
\end{center}
```

isn't exactly wrong but why centred inline math not a math display:

```
Or nous savons que 
\[
\operatorname{Var}(P)= \mathbb{E}[\operatornameVar(P/S(1))] + \operatornameVar(\mathbb{E}[P/S(1)])
\]
```

(never use math italic for multi-letter identifiers such as `Var`)
?

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you have an unbalanced brace in the second line of the third display. Also `^((1))` should be `^{(1)}`.

I spent some time to fix also several other mistakes and reordering the input.

The `hyperref` package should be last. For variance and covariance, use operator names; for repetitive tasks, define macros. For instance, I defined `\One` to stand for `\mathbb{1}`.

I also tried and fix the size of parentheses and the overfull lines (using `split`).

A display should never be preceded by a blank line; one can follow *provided* a new paragraph starts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside] {book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{hyperref} % should be last

\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ex}{\mathbb{E}}
\let\Pr\relax
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pr}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\One}{\mathbb{1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter[Nom court chapitre]{My chapter}

Quelques mots ici
\begin{align}
P-F_{1}(1)
  &=\sum_{i=1}^{r} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \One_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}X_{i} 
   -\sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}(S_{i}(1)-K_{i}) \\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^{r} \Bigl(\,\sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \One_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}X_{i}
   -M_{i}(S_{i}(1)-K_{i})\Bigr)
\end{align}
donc
\begin{align}
\Var(P-F_{1}(1))
  &=\Var(P) + \Var\Bigl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}(S_{i}(1)-K_{i})\Bigr) -2\Cov(P,F_{1}(1)) \\
\begin{split}
  &=\Var(P) + \sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}^2\Var(S_{i}(1)) \\
  &\qquad -2\Cov\Bigl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{r} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \One_{T_{j}^{i} 
                 \geqslant 1}X_{i},\sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}(S_{i}(1))\Bigr)
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
  &=\Var(P) + \sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}^2\Var(S_{i}(1)) \\
  &\qquad - 2\Bigl(\Ex\Bigl[\,\sum_{i=1}^{r} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \One_{T_{j}^{i} \geqslant 1}X_{i}
                  \sum_{l=1}^{r} M_{l}(S_{l}(1))\Bigr]-
                  \Ex[P]\Ex\Bigl[\,\sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}(S_{i}(1))\Bigr]\Bigr)
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
  &=\Var(P) + \sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}^2\Var(S_{i}(1)) \\
  &\qquad - 2\Bigl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}}\sum_{l=1}^{r} X_{i}M_{l}
              \Ex[\One_{T_{j}^{i} \geqslant 1}S_{l}(1)]-
              \Ex[P]\Ex\Bigl[\,\sum_{i=1}^{r} M_{i}(S_{i}(1))\Bigr]\Bigr)
\end{split}
\end{align}
Comme la fonction de survie est stochastique, les termes d'espérance et variance de $P$ doivent être détaillés:
\begin{align}
\Ex[\One_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}S_{l}(1)]
&=\Ex[\Ex[\One_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}S_{l}(1)/]\kappa_{1}^{(1)},\kappa_{1}^{(2)}] \\
&=\Ex[S_{l}(l)\Ex[\One_{T_{j}^{i}}/\kappa_{1}^{(1)},\kappa_{1}^{(2)}]
\end{align}
Nous avons également que
\begin{align}
\Ex[P] &=\sum_{i=1}^{r} X_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \Ex[\One_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}] \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{r} X_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \Ex[\Ex[\One_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}/S_{i}(1)]] \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{r} X_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \Ex[\Pr[T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1/S_{i}(1)]] \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{r} X_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{i}} \Ex[S_{i}(1)]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{r} X_{i}N_{i}\Ex[S_{i}(1)]
\end{align}
Or nous savons que
\begin{equation*}
\Var(P)= \Ex[\Var(P/S(1))] + \Var(\Ex[P/S(1)])
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close an opening `[` as well as an opening `{` I'm just quoting the relevant part of your code here:

```
Comme la fonction de survie est stochastique, les termes d'espérance et variance de P doivent être détaillés:

\begin{align}
   \mathbb{E}[\mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}S_{l}(1)]&=\mathbb{E}. [\mathbb{E}[\mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}\geqslant 1}S_{l}(1)/]\kappa_{1}^((1)),\kappa_{1}^((2))] \\
   &=\mathbb{E}[S_{l}(l)\mathbb{E}[\mathbb 1_{T_{j}^{i}}\kappa_{1}^((1)),\kappa_{1}^((2))]]
\end{align}
Nous avons également que
```

Notice the added closing `]` at the end and the closing `}` in `1_{T_{j}^{i}}`. I did not really bother to understand your calculations, so these may not actually be in the right places for the math to work out, but LaTeX compiles just fine for me after these changes.